# Python cgi does not work with requests

Tags: python, cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi
import cgitb
import json
import requests

print("Content-type: application/json\n")
print("making request...")
searchrequest = requests.get("https://google.com")
print(json.dumps(searchrequest.text))
```

following code works when executed from terminal, but when executed as cgi script, the output will only be "making request...", the program basically stopped running after request.get() had been executed.

Any ideas? Its so weird.

EDIT-1
    Problem resolved, it has nothing to do with the library itself. I figured out the problem after adding cgitb.enable() which enables the error report and tells me what the actual problem is.

Comment: It should be`https://www.google.com/`

Comment: as I said, the following code works when executed from terminal. I think the correctness of the url isn't what the problem here. Thanks for the answer though!